# Looking for the syntax for deleting a google spreadsheet using api call in react native

Tags: react-native, google-sheets-api

I have seen loads of examples where it is shown how to delete a row or a sheet inside a google spreadsheet, but i am trying to delete the spreadsheet itself and am stuck at the syntax. the below code does not do anything. Can someone please help out?

```
deleteSheet = async () => {
    const request = await fetch(
      `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets`,
      {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
          spreadsheetId: `Bearer ${SpreadsheetId}`,
        },
      }
    );
    const data = await request.json();
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to delete Google Spreadsheet.

For this, how about this answer?

In order to delete Google Spreadsheet, please use the Files: delete method in Drive API. Unfortunately, the Google Spreadsheet cannot be deleted using Sheets API.

#### From:

```
const request = await fetch(
  `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets`,
  {
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
      spreadsheetId: `Bearer ${SpreadsheetId}`,
    },
  }
);
```

#### To:

```
const request = await fetch(
  `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${SpreadsheetId}`,
  {
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
    },
  }
);
```

#### Note:

- In this case, "If successful, this method returns an empty response body." Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Files: delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete)

Comment: thanks Tanaike - the above worked - its very confusing though as there is no response send back - but it does delete the files

Comment: @apps ranevi Thank you for your response.